# Missing object values while passing value between C# classes

Tags: c#, .net

I have this method in the static class "ObjectMapper":

[image]

As we can see, the method has an object "dataReader" with some items ([0]). But... When I invoke this method:

[image]

The passed parameter is losing this record. Even changing the method "DataReaderToObjectList" from "public static" to "public", the value is losing this data. When my object has two or more records, it is being passed, but "killing" the first record. If I do it in the "classic" way, I can manipulate the dataReader correctly. But I need this method working, once it is used in several places in the application.

Comment: I bet the issue is you are expecting one way reader to restart every time you look at it... If you read something from DataReader you can't put it back...

Comment: Actually I'm passing the IDataReader as a filled object to another method, in another class.

Comment: No you are actually not passing it as a filled object

Answer (score 1):

In SelectAll() you call .Read()
Boom first record gone
You do NOTHING with that record

In DataReaderToObject
You call .Read()
Boom you are on the second record

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can only enumerate the contents of an `SqlDataReader` object one time.  This includes enumerating them in the `Results View` preview window.  The data is being lost in this specific instance because you are enumerating them in the debugger, which exhausts the reader, then stepping into the function with an exhausted reader

I think there is also a more fundamental error in your code.  You are calling the `Read` method twice on the same instance without actually enumerating any of the data that resulted from the first read.  You can fix this by removing the `Read` call in the `SelectAll` method

Comment: I forgot commenting, I reproduced twice to show my problem. I know this issue, but the problem is that the first record is being lost. Imagine a DataReader with five records. Ok? So... The method call is receiving this object (dataReader), but instead of passing with the FIVE records, is passing with FOUR records. In other words, the first record was lost.

Comment: @MatheusGelinski have you accounted for the double call to `Read`?  That would explain that precisely if i understand the problem

Comment: I tried two possibilities: the way as I posted in the print and: using (dataReader = DataAccessLayer.ExecuteReader(cmdType, "spcAddressTypeSelectAll", null))

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution for this problem, that solved (at least for now):

In the item 1, I declared a generic object that gets the attributes and values from dataReader and passed as a parameter (doing an explicit cast, as we can see) to a new method that gets this object as SqlDataReader, as shown in item 2 of image below.

[image]

This new method is placed in the same static class ObjectMapper, but oddly I'm being able to pass my object as parameter without losing any data. @Blam, your theory makes sense, but didn't worked here in this case.

Comment: My theory did not work?  Now you are not calling Read() in the first and not losing a record.  That is exactly what I said.  So you also had a casting problem.   Why is dataReader not a local variable?

Comment: Unfortunately not, and the first record still was being lost. I tested removing one of Read() that was being used, but the result was the same. The dataReader is an object IDataReader, that is used in several methods for the same reason, but in other methods it is working properly.

Comment: Oddly, other project (independent of this) use the same classes, with the same methods and works. I don't know why this got wrong...

Comment: If the first record is still being lost then why do you call it a solution?  And in what you posted as a solution but then claimed is not a solution you don't call read() in the first.